# Bootstrap colorpicker doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

Bootstrap colorpicker doesn't work. This is my code

```
 <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:-10px">
   <label style=" height:20px !important ;font-size: 12px;" class="col-sm-4 
    control-label">Kurye Durum Renk</label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input id="ColorPickerKuryeDurumRenk" type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
 </div>


<link rel="stylesheet" src="plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">
<script src="plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#ColorPickerKuryeDurumRenk").colorpicker();
    });

</script>
```

When i runned the code like this, I didn't get any error but the colorpicker doesn't work . Where is my fail ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any script or resource errors in the browser console?

Comment: [Seems to be working fine](https://jsfiddle.net/kpwcfht4/), make sure your CSS/JS files are actually being loaded.

Comment: bootstrap required `jQuery` for bootstrap.js to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<link rel="stylesheet" src="plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">`

To import a stylesheet you need to use href="PATH_OF_FILE"

Comment: yea i imported sir

Comment: Ohhh my bad sir :( i changed the src.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it is your lib path wrong or reference not correct.

try to use the following, if it is working then you can **debug** by removing them one by one (and use your local reference instead)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group"style="margin-top:-10px">
   <label style=" height:20px !important ;font-size: 12px;" class="col-sm-4 
    control-label">Kurye Durum Renk</label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input id="ColorPickerKuryeDurumRenk" type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
 </div>


<link rel="stylesheet" src="plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">
<script src="plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ColorPickerKuryeDurumRenk").colorpicker();
    });
</script>
```